# How to find the smallest positive integer number $n$ such that $a^n≡1 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a prime $p$ and number $a$ isn't divided by $p$, how do I find the smallest positive integer number $n$ such that $a^n≡1\pmod p$?

Example for $a=10; p=13$; $n$ would be $6$.

Is there an algorithms that faster than brute-force with $O(p)$?

Comment: Is this for cryptography?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Comment: @Arthur That's for general equations of the form $a^n \equiv b$, but surely something can be said for the specific case that $b = 1$.

Comment: Maybe, Euler's theorem can help (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) or, even better, you can consider Carmichael's function. Another very powerful tool is Zsigmondy's theorem...